# new WebView() causes "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: not implemented"

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I cannot create a new WebView programatically. Simply calling `new WebView()` causes the following exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<clinit>(WebEngine.java:339)
    at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:260)
    // omitting unrelated stacktraces
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventFilterRecord.handleCapturingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:282)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchCapturingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:98)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchCapturingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:223)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchCapturingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:180)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchCapturingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:43)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:52)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:4058)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:4004)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2121)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2595)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:547)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:971)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: not implemented
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.logging.PlatformLogger.getName(PlatformLogger.java:121)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.perf.PerfLogger.fullName(PerfLogger.java:155)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.perf.PerfLogger.registerProbe(PerfLogger.java:201)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.perf.PerfLogger.startCount(PerfLogger.java:227)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.perf.PerfLogger.<init>(PerfLogger.java:90)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.perf.PerfLogger.getLogger(PerfLogger.java:57)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.perf.PerfLogger.getLogger(PerfLogger.java:84)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.Invoker.<clinit>(Invoker.java:34)
    ... 37 more
```

Is it a bug? I am using OpenJFX 11.0.1 and OpenJDK 11.0.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Updates:*

As mentioned in the comments this bug will be fixed in OpenJFX 12.

- [GitHub Issue #334](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/334) (submitted by questioner)
- [GitHub Pull Request #343](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/pull/343)
- [JBS Issue JDK-8216470](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216470)

---

Here's the problem code from `com.sun.javafx.logging.PlatformLogger`:

```
@Override
public String getName() {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
}
```

As you can see, it does nothing but throw the observed exception. This is true of all the "implemented" `java.lang.System.Logger` methods.

If you follow the code, as outlined by the stack trace you provide, the `getName` method is invoked ultimately because a `com.sun.webkit.perf.PerfLogger` is instantiated during the process of initializing the `WebEngine` and, by extension, `com.sun.webkit.Invoker` classes. However, `getName` is only called when the `PerfLogger` is enabled.

From a cursory glance, a `PerfLogger` wraps a `com.sun.javafx.logging.PlatformLogger` which itself wraps a `System.Logger`. The `PerfLogger` is enabled if the `System.Logger` returns true for `isLoggable(System.Logger.Level.FINE)` at the time the `PerfLogger` is constructed.

In this case, this process results in a `System.Logger` with the name `"com.sun.webkit.perf.Locks"` being created. What this means is that you can avoid the `UnsupportedOperationException` if you configure this `System.Logger` to not log anything at `Level.FINE` or "lower". Doing this will make the `PerfLogger` "disabled" which prevents `getName` from being called down the line.

*Note: This is based on the source code of OpenJFX 11.0.1. Everything mentioned is an implementation detail and can change without notice.*

Comment: Nice investigation. You are right, it turns that I am setting the default logging level in `logging.properties` as `.level = ALL`. Adding the following two lines solved the issue: `com.sun.webkit.perf.Locks.level = OFF` `com.sun.webkit.perf.WCFontPerfLogger.level = OFF`.

Comment: This has been fixed now and OpenJFX 12 will not have this bug.

Comment: This has been fixed by https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/pull/343